# R Markdown not rendering some HTML?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

When I knit an R Markdown file with the following code, not all of the HTML is rendered. Any thoughts on what is happening here?

#### R Markdown file

```
---
title: "html test"
author: "NA"
date: "1/16/2021"
output: html_document
---

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item1"> col1 </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item2"> col2 </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item3"> col3 </div>
</div>
```

#### Output

[image: R Markdown output]

However, when I put the same code into a `HTML` file and open it in a web browser, it renders just fine.

[image: Using an HTML file]

Comment: That's because the inner `div`s are indented and then a code block is rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, see: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-content.html:

````
---
title: "html test"
author: "NA"
date: "1/16/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{=html}
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item1"> col1 </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item2"> col2 </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item3"> col3 </div>
</div>
```
````